# How to suppress messages in R chunk output?

Tags: r

I want to execute the following R chunk, but when I generate the PDF of the RMarkdown I don't want to include the Loading messages.

**Knitr Setup chunk**

`{r setup, include=FALSE}
knitr::opts_chunk$set(echo = TRUE)
knitr::opts_knit$set(progress=FALSE)`

**Load Packages**

````
```{r, warning=FALSE, results='hide',message='hide'}
x <- c("ggmap", "rgdal", "rgeos", "maptools", "dplyr", "tidyr", "tmap")
lapply(x, library, character.only = TRUE) # load the required packages
```
````

**Output I'm getting**

### [image]

**Wanted Output**

Only the chunk in the pdf without messages of loading packages.

Comment: This question is not a duplicate as the suggested answer in the referenced question I'm supposedly duplicating says to set include= FALSE. I don't want to hide the chunk...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The message option takes a logical argument (i.e., TRUE/FALSE): [See knitr documentation](https://yihui.name/knitr/options/#text-results).

This sould work:

````
```{r, warning=FALSE, results='hide',message=FALSE}
x <- c("ggmap", "rgdal", "rgeos", "maptools", "dplyr", "tidyr", "tmap")
lapply(x, library, character.only = TRUE) # load the required packages
```
````

Answer (score 1):

There is a base function `suppressPackageStartupMessages` that serves this purpose. Wrapping your expression will prevent the text from printing to the console.

```
x <- c("ggmap", "rgdal", "rgeos", "maptools", "dplyr", "tidyr", "tmap")
suppressPackageStartupMessages(lapply(x, library, character.only = TRUE))
```

Comment: This works fine but will show up in the knitted document.

Comment: @JonGrub, if you look at the duplicate answer that I linked to, you will see you could have a separate chunk to load your packages and set the chunk option `include=FALSE`, which is the standard approach.

Answer (score 1):

I use the `pacman` library

```
pacman::p_load(ggmap, rgdal, rgeos, maptools, dplyr, tidyr, tmap)
```